# Sorts a bunch of words by the number of character “a”s within the word

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to write a function that sorts a bunch of words by the number of
character “a”s within the word (decreasing order). If some words
contain the same amount of character “a”s then you need to sort
those words by their lengths.

Input :

```
["aaaasd", "a", "aab", "aaabcd", "ef", "cssssssd", "fdz", "kf",
"zc", "lklklklklklklklkl", "l"]
```

Output :

```
["aaaasd", "aaabcd", "aab", "a", "lklklklklklklklkl", "cssssssd",
"fdz", "ef", "kf", "zc", "l"]
```

I have tried finding the answers but nothing is very specific.

Comment: This honestly looks suspiciously much like a homework question. Can you show what you've tried yourself other than "I've tried to find the answer"? I mean, the point is that you actually learn something. If others just do your job for you instead of telling you where you went wrong, you won't be able to solve this issue the next time you encounter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin `array#sort` method can be used with a custom comparator function. Here's an exmaple that behaves the way you described.

```js
const dat = ["aaaasd", "a", "aab", "aaabcd", "ef", "cssssssd", "fdz", "kf",
"zc", "lklklklklklklklkl", "l"]

function sortByAs(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const diff =  numberOfAs(b) - numberOfAs(a);
    // different #s of A, return the comparison
    if (diff !== 0) return diff;
    // fallback to length comparison
    return b.length - a.length;
  });
}
function numberOfAs(str) {
  const matches = str.match(/a/g) || [];
  return matches.length;
}

console.log(sortByAs(dat));
```